# How to write a streaming dataframe into another Kafka Topic after doing some transformations?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read data from a Kafka topic, join it with another dataframe from Hive table and save the result to another Kafka topic.
Below is the code I have written.

```
# Returns a dataframe after reading Kafka topic.
kafka_df = kafka_data(spark=spark, kafkaconfig=kafkaconfig, tableconfig=table_config, source_type='kafka', where_clause='', objectname='object_name')

#Write the dataframe returned from above step into another Kafka topic.
write_batches(kafka_df)

def write_batches(kafka_df):
  table_config = po_header_config
  kafka_config = kafkaconfig
  
  jaas_config = kafka_config['jaas_config']
  oauth_client = f" oauth.client.id='{kafka_config['client_id']}'"
  oauth_secret = f" oauth.client.secret='{kafka_config['client_secret']}'"
  oauth_token_endpoint_uri = f" oauth.token.endpoint.uri='{kafka_config['endpoint_uri']}'"
  oauth_config = jaas_config + oauth_client + oauth_secret + oauth_token_endpoint_uri + " oauth.max.token.expiry.seconds='30000' ;"

  kafka_df.writeStream \
  .option('checkpointLocation', table_config['checkpoint_location']) \
  .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', kafka_config['kafka_broker']) \
  .option('topic', kafka_config['topic_name']) \
  .format('kafka') \
  .foreachBatch(join_kafka_streams_final_table_test) \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .trigger(processingTime="300 seconds") \
  .start().awaitTermination()


def join_kafka_streams_final_table_test(kafka_df, batch_id):
    try:
        table_config = config
        filters = data_filter(kafka_df=kafka_df)
        query = f'select * from DB.TABLE where {filters}'
        main_df = spark.sql(query)
        print(f'Joining kafka dataframe with final_table table')
        joined_df = join_remove_duplicate_col(kafka_df=kafka_df, final_table=main_df, table_config=table_config)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'Join failed with the exception: {error}')
        traceback.print_exc()
        print('Stopping the application')
        sys.exit(1)     


def join_remove_duplicate_col(kafka_df, final_table: DataFrame, table_config: dict):
    try:
        df = kafka_df.join(final_table, on=table_config['join_keys'], how='left_outer')
        print('Join Successful.')
        repeated_columns = [c for c in kafka_df.columns if c in final_table.columns]
        for column in repeated_columns:
            df = df.drop(final_table[column])
        return df
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'Unable join kafka_df & final_table table with the exception: {error}')
        traceback.print_exc()
        sys.exit(1)

def data_filter(kafka_df):
  try:
      print('Preparing filters for final_table table')
      lst = []
      distinct_partitions = kafka_df.select('main_part', 'create_dt').withColumn('month_part', substring('create_dt', 1, 7)).drop('create_dt').distinct()
      filters = distinct_partitions.groupby('main_part').agg(F.concat_ws("', '", F.collect_list(distinct_partitions.month_part))).rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], row[1])).collectAsMap()
      for key, value in filters.items():
          s = "'" + value + "'"
          lst.append(f"(super_main_part = '{key}' and month_part in ({s}))")
      datafilter = ' or '.join(lst)
      return datafilter
  except Exception as error:
      print(f'Unable to form filter for final_table table with the exception: {error}')
      traceback.print_exc()
      print('Stopping the application')
      sys.exit(1)
```

The problem here is when I invoke the method `write_batches` with my Kafka dataframe, I don't see any print statements from the methods present inside `join_kafka_streams_final_table_test` which is executed foreachBatch

The stream just loads and does nothing.
Could anyone let me know if my syntax is in the right format ? If not, what is the mistake I did here and how can I correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that came to my mind:

1. In the current code, you are using `format("kafka")` **and** `foreachBatch(join_kafka_streams_final_table_test)` at the same time. Typically, you would only use one of them.
2. The method `join_kafka_streams_final_table_test` does not contain any actions such as writing, hence, it will never be executed.

Looking at the overall code, I really recommend to get familiar with the [Structured Streaming Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#structured-streaming-programming-guide). As I am not completely familiar with Python I can only guess what you are trying to achieve, but the programming model of a structured streaming application already allows you to handle Dataframes within a batch. So instead of calling explictly `foreachBatch` you could do something as below:

```py
table_config = po_header_config
kafka_config = kafkaconfig

# Returns a dataframe after reading Kafka topic.
kafka_df = kafka_data(spark=spark, kafkaconfig=kafkaconfig, tableconfig=table_config, source_type='kafka', where_clause='', objectname='object_name')

table_config = config
filters = data_filter(kafka_df=kafka_df)
query = f'select * from DB.TABLE where {filters}'
main_df = spark.sql(query)
df = kafka_df.join(main_df, on=table_config['join_keys'], how='left_outer')

df.writeStream \
  .option('checkpointLocation', table_config['checkpoint_location']) \
  .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', kafka_config['kafka_broker']) \
  .option('topic', kafka_config['topic_name']) \
  .format('kafka') \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .trigger(processingTime="300 seconds") \
  .start().awaitTermination()
```

Again, not completely familiar with the Python syntax, but I hope you get the idea.